# Как преобразовать чёрно-белую картинку в одномерный массив?

Tags: javascript, html5, изображения, canvas

Задача: взять чёрно-белое изображение с canvas и перевести его в массив из 1 и 0, где 1 - чёрный цвет, 0 - белый.

Моя функция преобразования

```
function convertData(imgdata) {
    convert = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < imgdata.length; i+=4) {
        if (imgdata[i] <= 0)
            convert.push(1);
        else
            convert.push(0);
    }
    return convert;
}
```

На вход функции подаётся `ImageData` картинки

```
ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
```

Если я использую эту функция на изображении которое я загрузил через `<input type="file">` и отрисовал на канве, то всё работает правильно (например, загружаю изображение 2х2 где закрашен только первый пиксель и функция возвращает `[1, 0, 0, 0]`)

Но когда я её использую на изображении, которое я нарисовал на холсте мышкой, то результат получается странным и неправильным. И оно работает так как нужно только, если я отредактирую функцию следующий образом

```
function convertData(imgdata) {
    convert = [];
    for (var i = 3; i < imgdata.length; i+=4) {
        if (imgdata[i] > 0)
            convert.push(1);
        else
            convert.push(0);
    }
    return convert;
}
```

То есть первый вариант функции работает для изображений, которые я загрузил и отрисовал на канве, но не работает, если я мышкой рисую изображение. Вторая же функция наоборот.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

При рисовании мышкой у вас не чётко чёрные пиксели и поэтому они не определяются. У вас вторая функция вообще не по какому-либо rgb-цвету перебирает как в первой функции, а по прозрачности, т. к. `i = 3` - это прозрачность первого пикселя. Естественно это работает, т. к. все остальные пиксели прозрачны.

Вот так должно работать и мышкой и с картинкой:

```
function convertData(imgdata)
{
    convert = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < imgdata.length; i+=4)
    {
        if(imgdata[i] < 128)
            convert.push(1);
        else
            convert.push(0);
    }
    return convert;
}
```

Comment: Это немного улучшит результат преобразования, но это не то, что мне нужно. Такое ощущение, что структура ImageData разная у картинки, которую я загружаю и у той, что я рисую мышкой. Поэтому мне для мышки приходиться использовать изначальное смещение индекса var i = 3, а для загружаемой var i = 0 и плюс еще менять знак с > на <=

Comment: @RealPeha, немного дополнил описание вашей ошибки в моём ответе. Мне не очень понятно для чего вам это нужно? Опишите задачу подробней.

Comment: Извините, что долго не отвечал, дело в том, что я решил свою проблему) Но Вы мне определенно помогли, спасибо!

Comment: @RealPeha, это хорошо, что помог! ;-) Обращайтесь!